# Location client on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, locationlistener

I have been developing app that uses location client class to get user location. I have tested it on my Nexus devices, some Sony xperia devices and it works no problem. But then there is sammy S3 mini. It just does not even kick in to try to get location... Also I had to reboot it to get geocoder to work, but still no locations. Is there a different path to get locations on Samsung devices to work?

Comment: works for me on s2 and s3. Maybe your device has some capabilities disabled in settings? You need to post some code and what unexpected results you see.

Comment: All settings were on like on Nexus or xperia phones... I have location listener to do some work on location changed and expected is to run asynctask... All other devices do the right call, only sammy phone does not

Comment: I will have another sammy device in a hour ill try it again, if it will not kick ill post code also, but I dont belive it could be code related as other devices work...

Comment: I am seeing this issue on some Samsung phones. Have you found a fix for this issue ?

Comment: @DrkStr Was a long time ago. But in short it just started working in some point.

Comment: @xoolooo thanks man. Any idea on what fixed it.